# Flutter async await not functioning in order

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I am working on a project where I have employees scan items into a bin. I am trying to load the information from the database. I have looked at many different posts and found things similar, but never anything that worked.

I have a list (binListDBList) that I am adding data into, then I want to do stuff with it after. I do get a response and it is the correct data, but I have to do a timed delay instead of await. It is clunky and am wondering what a better solution would be.

I have tried async/await and .then and nothing has worked so far. I know there is a solution, but I have spent a lot of time and haven't gotten anywhere.

I have added in a bunch of print statements for testing.

Starting method:

```
Future<void> loadBinListFromDB(String empID, String binName) async {
  print("start");
  DatabaseService.binListDBList.clear();
  print("Zero: " + DatabaseService.binListDBList.toString());


  await DatabaseService().getBinList(empID, binName);

  print("test");

  if (DatabaseService.binListDBList.isEmpty) {
    print("No Data");
  } else {
    print("data");
  }
  print("Fifth: " + DatabaseService.binListDBList.toString());

  Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) {
    print("last: " + DatabaseService.binListDBList.toString());
  });

  print(DatabaseService.binListDBList);
  return;
}
```

DatabaseService class

```
static List<BinListDB> binListDBList = [];

Future<void> getBinList(String employeeID, String binName) async {
    print(employeeID);

    List<BinListDB> hold = [];
    print("First: $binListDBList");
    binListCollection
        .doc(employeeID)
        .collection(binName)
        .snapshots()
        .forEach((element) {
      for (int i = 0; i < element.docs.length; i++) {
        hold.add(BinListDB.fromFireStore(element.docs[i]));
      }
      print("Second: $binListDBList");
      binListDBList = hold;
      print("Third: $binListDBList");
    });
    print("Fourth: $binListDBList");
    return;

  }
```

output:

```
I/flutter (26448): start
I/flutter (26448): Zero: []
I/flutter (26448): EmployeeID
I/flutter (26448): First: []
I/flutter (26448): Fourth: []
I/flutter (26448): test
I/flutter (26448): No Data
I/flutter (26448): Fifth: []
I/flutter (26448): finish
I/flutter (26448): Second: []
I/flutter (26448): Third: [Instance of 'BinListDB']
I/flutter (26448): last: [Instance of 'BinListDB']
```

I don't understand why it isn't printing in order.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not in delays at the terminal itself?
I had a similar problem in other languages several times and it was just the problem with  "typing" in the terminal. Maybe you can put the data into a array and print it at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently are doing:

> ```dart
>     binListCollection
>         .doc(employeeID)
>         .collection(binName)
>         .snapshots()
>         .forEach((element) {
>       ...
>     });
> ```

[`snapshots()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/snapshots.html) returns a `Stream`, which is asynchronous. You call [`Stream.forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/forEach.html) to iterate over each element of the `Stream`, and `Stream.forEach` returns a `Future` to indicate when it's complete, but you neglect to `await` that `Future`.  The caller of `Stream.forEach` therefore continues executing immediately, and you see "Fourth" printed (and later "Fifth" and "finished") before `Stream.forEach`'s callback prints "Second" and "Third".

That is, you need to change it to:

```dart
    await binListCollection
        .doc(employeeID)
        .collection(binName)
        .snapshots()
        .forEach((element) {
      ...
    });
```

I strongly suggest enabling the [`unawaited_futures` lint](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#unawaited_futures) to let the analyzer catch such errors.

Comment: What is the difference from what I am doing? 
I should mention that in FireStore the data is structured as such:
(Collection > Document > Collection > Document > Fields)

BinList > EmployeeID > binName > itemID > Fields

Comment: @mjdk99 As I stated, you need to `await` your call of `Stream.forEach`.  I've updated my answer for clarity.